# Equivalent to dbms_output in Soapui JDBC step?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, soapui, dbms-output

I got a question nobody seems to care about because I have not found anything on the the web.

I am using the free version of SOAPUI. I use some JDBC steps (Oracle driver) in my testCases.
In my SQL code, it would be very usefull for me to output some traces for debbuging.

But the dbms_output.put_lines does not seem to trace anything. I look at all the 'log' windows in soapUI, but I found nothing.

Can you help me ?
Do I look at the wrong window ?
Is there a special command-line to use in my SQL code to print my output ?

Thankx in advance

Comment: The output of `dbms_output` does not magically appear somewhere. The Java code needs to explicitly retrieve messages from the Oracle server using the `dbms_output.get_line` procedure. I highly doubt that SOAPUI does that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I guess you're right. That's why I am asking if there is a way to make SQL trace in Soapui JDBC Step.